# Why is scala failing to infer the type of mapped NodeSeq?

Tags: scala, dictionary, type-inference

I'm trying to pull the ids out of the `id` attribute of a set of xml elements, but it fails with a type error:

```
scala> (xml \\ "contentitem").map( (_ \ "@id").text )
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$bslash("@id"))
       (xml \\ "contentitem").map( (_ \ "@id").text )
                                    ^
```

When I explicitly provide a named val (`elem`) in my map, it works:

```
scala> (xml \\ "contentitem").map( elem => (elem \ "@id").text )
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String] = List(20761, 22798, 22799, 21167, 21438, 20770, 21480, 21906, 21907, 21923, 22766, 22771, 22794, 22800, 22803, 22804, 22818, 22819, 22820, 22821)
```

I don't understand the difference here.  How is `elem` different from `_`?

Comment: In the first case it's `map( (x => x \ "@id").text )`, not what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala is looking for the most inner part which forms "complete" expression when converting placeholder syntax to an anonymous function. Not let's look at your example:

```
(_ \ "@id").text
```

in fact contains another complete expression inside it:

```
_ \ "@id"
```

So this expression instead is converted to an anonymous function:

```
x => x \ "@id"
```

which is then used in the outer expression as:

```
(x => x \ "@id").text
```

Now in this expression there is no way to infer the type of `x`, hence your error message:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$bslash("@id"))
```

**UPDATE**

`_` alone is not considered a complete expression, so the code `.map(List(_))` works since the most inner complete expression is `List(_)` and it will be converted to `x => List(x)`

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions

Answer (score 1):

When you write something like this:

`list map(_.toInt)`

you directly tell the compiler that you want to map elements of `list`. When you write:

```
(xml \\ "contentitem").map( elem => (elem \ "@id").text )
```

You tell the compiler that you want to take `elem` and map it, which is the same as my previous example but more explicit. However, when you write:

`(xml \\ "contentitem").map( (_ \ "@id").text )`

You do not tell it that you want to use elements of the collection implicitly (my first example) or explicitly (your second example). Instead, you tell it to take anything `_` and extract the id.

TLDR; it does not fail to infer the type. You do not tell the compiler what you want.